# Create histogram from two arrays

Tags: python, list, numpy, nested-lists

I have two numpy arrays with the same dimensions: weights, and percents. Percents is 'real' data, and the weights is how many of each 'real' data there is in the histogram.

Eg)

```
weights = [[0, 1, 1, 4, 2]
           [0, 1, 0, 3, 5]]
percents = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

(every row of percents is the same)

I would like to "multiply" these together in such a way that I produce weights[x] * [percents[x]]:

```
results = [[0 * [1] + 1 * [2] + 1 * [3] + 4 * [4] + 2 * [5]
           [0 * [1] + 1 * [2] + 0 * [3] + 3 * [4] + 5 * [5]]
        = [[2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]
           [2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

Notice that the lengths of each row can be different.. Ideally this can be done in numpy but because of this it may end up being a list of lists.

Edit:
I've been able to cobble together these nested for loops but obviously it's not ideal:

```
list_of_hists = []
for index in df.index:
    hist = []
    # Create a list of lists, later to be flattened to 'results'
    for i, percent in enumerate(percents):
        hist.append(
        # For each percent, create a list of [percent] * weight
            [percent]
            * int(
                df.iloc[index].values[i]
            )
        )
    # flatten the list of lists in hist
    results = [val for list_ in hist for val in list_]
    list_of_hists.append(results)
```

Comment: You don't actually need looping. But since the lenght of arrays of your input is unbalanced, something like `np.split` could be a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list-comprehension and `reduce` from `functools`:

```py
import functools
res=[functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,
                [x*[y] for x, y in zip(w, p)])
                for w, p in zip(weights, percents)]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
[[2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5],
 [2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

Or, just list-comprehension solution only:

```py
res= [[j for i in [x*[y]
              for x, y in zip(w, p)]
                for j in i]
    for w, p in zip(weights, percents)]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
[[2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5],
 [2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

Comment: This is great, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

There is a `np.repeat` designed for such kind of operations but it doesn't work in 2D case. So you need to work with flattened views of arrays instead.

```
weights = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 4, 2], [0, 1, 0, 3, 5]])
percents = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
>>> np.repeat(percents.ravel(), weights.ravel())
array([2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])
```

And after that you need to select index locations where to split it:

```
>>> np.split(np.repeat(percents.ravel(), weights.ravel()), np.cumsum(np.sum(weights, axis=1)[:-1]))
[array([2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]), array([2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])]
```

Note that `np.split` is quite unefficient operation as well as your wish to make array out of rows of unequal lenghts.

Comment: This is also a clever solution, thank you!